# Where can I find an English translation of Grauert's paper?

Tags: reference-request, translation, dg.differential-geometry

The german title is : Holomorphe Funktionen mit Werten in komplexen Lieschen Gruppen.

Comment: I am sure that there has never been a translation into English. But all of the results are proven using a different approach in Gromov's paper: Oka's principle for holomorphic sections of elliptic bundles. If all you need are the results, that should suffice.

Comment: Thank you. I will look into it. Is Grauert's argument shown in any book?